# Limit of matrix power existence

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Say $A$ is a $3\times 3$ matrix with determinant 1. Assume that there exists an $x\in\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}A^nx=v$ for some $v\in\mathbb{R}^3\setminus \{ 0,x \} $. Show that $A$ has only real eigenvalues. Note that we don't know if $A$'s entries are real.

Can we conclude $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}A^n$ exists? If so, then it seems like the question is asking me to use diagonalization, and if I recall correctly $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}A^n$ exists only if the eigenvalues are 1 or with norm less then 1. So if there are complex eigenvalues, the determinant cannot be 1. Is this correct? But I am still confused because even if $A$ has only real eigenvalues this would mean $A$ only has 1 as eigenvalues, and the dimension of eigenspace is 3. Then $A$ is just $I$ which is also contradiction. If we cannot conclude  $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}A^n$ exists then I am not sure where to start.

**Edit:** This problem has another two questions: b) Show that there is a $y\in\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}A^{-n}y=v$, and $y\neq v$; c) Show that $x$, $y$, and $v$ are linearly independent. After coming up with a possible solution to part a) in the comments below, I am not seeing connections with part b) and c). This makes me think there is some key concept or trick this question is asking that I am not aware of.

Comment: @Salcio In that example $v$ will be equal to $x$, which is not allowed.

Comment: $1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, since $Av=v$. This means that the eigenvalues of $A$ are $1, \lambda, \lambda^{-1}$.

Comment: @Crostul What about the case 1 has multiplicity 3 and the eigenspace doesn't have dimension 3? This seems complicated

Comment: Only the identity matrix satisfies that condition.

Answer (score 1):

An easy counterexample is $$A = \begin{bmatrix}2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \frac12\end{bmatrix}.$$ Here, if $x = (0,1,1)$, then the limit of $A^nx$ as $n \to \infty$ is $(0,1,0)$, which is neither the zero vector nor $x$. However, the limit of $A^n$ as $n \to \infty$ does not exist, because $$A^n = \begin{bmatrix}2^n & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2^{-n}\end{bmatrix}$$ and the top left entry blows up.

Comment: That's a good example. I had the feeling this was not true but I did not try to construct an example. I guess another way I can try to tackle the problem is say $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are not real, $\lambda_1\lambda_2\lambda_3=1$, $x=x_1+x_2+x_3$ where $x_i$ are eigenvectors, then $A^nx=\lambda_1^nx_1+\lambda_2^nx_2+\lambda_3^nx_3$. Then we have that either $\lambda_1\lambda_2>1$, forcing $x_1=x_2=0$, $\lambda_3<1$ and hence $v=0$, or $\lambda_1\lambda_2<1$, forcing $x_3=0$, and $v=0$, or $\lambda_1\lambda_2=1$, forcing $x_1=x_2=0$, $\lambda_3=1$ and $x=v$. Is this on the right track?

Comment: The difference for the complex case is that when $\lambda_1\lambda_2=1$, since they are conjugate, they both have to have norm 1, and $\lambda_i^n$ won't converge for $i=1,2$?

Comment: It looks like to have the limit condition, we need one eigenvalue of $1$ ($v$ is its eigenvector) and at least one eigenvalue with norm (or absolute value) less than $1$. This means that for determinant $1$, we also need a third eigenvalue with norm more than $1$, and now there are no conjugate pairs to form.